# Getting hierarchical positions of <ul> and <li> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get how deeply nested my li's are using jquery, and then create a string containing the li's and numbers on how deeply they are nested. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    MenuItem1
    </li>

    <li>
    MenuItem2
        <ul>
            <li>
            SubItemA
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
    MenuItem3
    </li>
</ul>
```

should produce `"0:MenuItem1  0:MenuItem2  1:SubItemA  0:MenuItem3"` or at least something similar like that. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
var text = $('li').map(function() {
     var num_parents = $(this).parents('ul').length;
     // or .parentsUntil('#someId', 'ul') if you have `$('#someID li')` above
     return (num_parents - 1) + ': ' + $(this).contents().map(function() {
         if(this.nodeType === 3) {
             return $.trim(this.nodeValue);
         }
         return null;
     }).get().join('');
}).get().join(' ');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cXJ8/)

Depending on your actual HTML structure, you can also simplify retrieving the text of a `li` element to

```
return (num_parents - 1) + ': ' + $.trim(this.firstChild);
```

if the text directly follows the opening `<li>` tag.

Or if you have other tags inside each `li` element (like `span` or `div`) and you want to get their content as well, you can clone the current node and remove all `ul` descendants:

```
var text = $.trim($(this).clone().find('ul').remove().end().text());
return (num_parents - 1) + ': ' + text;
```

**Reference:** [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents), [`parentsUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/), [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)