# Nested elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to either select the parent element(s) with the `.plugin-class-name` class.
Alternatively, I could also make do with a list of childs that have the same class. (so no parents)

The problem is that when I use .find() I get both the parents **and** the children.

Some of my code:

```js
console.log($('#parentId').find('.plugin-class-name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentId">
  <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
  <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
  <div class="plugin-class-name">
  <div id="childId1">
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="childId2">
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use immediate child selector for targeting parent elements:

```
$('#parentId > .plugin-class-name')
```

Comment: I can't use #parentId > .plugin-class-name because I don't know what the html structure will be

Comment: so on what basis element becomes parent or child?

Comment: @JarosławWróblewski: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8986440/1719752?

Answer (score 0):

I will give more use examples:

```html
<div id="parentId">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="plugin-class-name">
        <div id="childId1">
          <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
          <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
          <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
          <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="childId2">
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
    <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="plugin-class-name"></div>
</div>
```